# What does it mean to have a dimension of $1.5$?

Tags: geometry, spacetime-dimensions, fractals

**Question.** How do I explain to my dad what it means for some object to have a dimension of $1.5$?

---

**My attempt.** I tried to tell him the definition for an object to have a dimension $D$: if we scale up every dimension of the object by a factor of $S$, then the resultant object is comprised of $S^D$ copies of the original object. Then I failed to provide him with a convincing example; I even confused myself during the trial of convincing him. So, here I am. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: The examples are fractals. But this is not a physics question.

Comment: a line segment has length $l$, a square made with those line segments as sides has area $l^2$, a cube with the line segment as edges has volume $l^3$, and so on...

Comment: 50% more........

Comment: The [Minkowski sausage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_sausage) has fractal dimension 1.5, exactly.

Comment: Mathematicians are so dramatic. These fractals are 2d. They have some particular property about how their area or length or something scales when you change the size of the object - and how its different from other normal 2d objects. But that doesn't mean you should let them confuse you about what a spatial dimension is.

Comment: To elucidate fractional dimensions, you may want to show something simpler, like an object with dimension between 0 and 1, e.g. the Cantor discontinuum. Then you can state that it works alike for objects that partially fill planes, having dimensions between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I explain to my dad what it means for some object to have a dimension of 1.5?

Show him the [Minkowski sausage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_sausage) fractal curve. It has a [fractal dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) of exactly 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Fractional (or fractal) dimensions are used for shapes that have a perimeter or area that is fractal in some way. In fractals, the shape gets more and more complex as you zoom in to it. A good example is a coastline: depending on how closely you follow the bays, inlets, puddles, grains of sand and even molecules, the measured length of the coastline changes. The smaller the detail, the longer it gets.

For example, to construct the Koch curve, you start with a line segment. The central third of it is replaced by 2 segments at 30 degrees. Then each of the shorter segments is manipulated in the same way, and so on at infinitum. No matter how far you zoom ito the Koch curve, it will always look the same. As a result, the distance between any 2 points on the curve is infinite, and the Koch curve has a dimension or 1.262.

Start by having a look at Wikipedia's ["Fractal dimension" page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension).

As @GSmith said in a comment, the Minkowski Sausage has a dimension of 1.5. To see what it looks like, try [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minkowski%20sausage&lk=0) and enter the number of iterations you would like (it starts with 3). Using 0 iterations, the shape is a square. As the number of iterations increases, the length of the curve grows without bounds while the enclosed area remains the same as the square (1).